# Reducing conditional operators efficiently

Tags: java, android, sonarqube

**What I am trying to perform:** I am trying to reduce the conditional operators, Since Sonar is giving a error for it

```
     if (!parseBooleanFromString(response.getBuy().getHasEligibleAccounts()) &&
                            (!parseBooleanFromString(response.getSell().getHasEligibleAccounts()) &&
                                    (!parseBooleanFromString(response.getExchange().getHasEligibleAccounts()) &&
                                            (!parseBooleanFromString(response.getWorkplaceRetirement().getHasPlansEligibleForChangeContributions()) &&
                                                    (!parseBooleanFromString(response.getWorkplaceRetirement().getHasPlansEligibleForChangeInvestments())))))) {

                        //Success
                    } else {
                        //Failure
 }

     private boolean parseBooleanFromString(String mStr) {
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(mStr);
        }
```

**What i have tried**: 
I am trying to put all the boolean values in a list and check

### Is that the best way to do or is there a more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

You can also move these conditions into different functions which internally calls other functions and returns single boolean result. This way there will only one function in above if condition which will internally evaluate and returns result.

Comment: sonar will still give error but now in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're checking if each statement is false, how about you keep a global integer in memory: `private int product = 1;`. Make a separate method where you calculate the product (replaces the string to boolean parser):

```
private void updateProduct(String mStr){
    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(mStr)) //If true, condition should fail
        product *= 0;
    else
        product *= 1;
}
```

In essence, you are not running 'if statement' but multiplying the boolean:

```
product = 1;

updateProduct(response.getBuy().getHasEligibleAccounts());
updateProduct(response.getSell().getHasEligibleAccounts());
//etc

if (product > 0){
    //success
} else {
    //failure
}
```

Explanation: If at any point a condition was true, the product will always be 0. The only instance where the product is > 0 is when all statements were false

Comment: Is `product *= 1` ... means `product`=`product`*`1` and globally i should declare `product` as `1` in the begining

Comment: @Devrath yes, that's what it means =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what sonar complains about, but you have alot of redundant parenthesis and confusing negations. Using DeMorgans law, you can at least simplify to:

```
    boolean b = parseBooleanFromString(response.getBuy().getHasEligibleAccounts())
            || parseBooleanFromString(response.getSell().getHasEligibleAccounts())
            || parseBooleanFromString(response.getExchange().getHasEligibleAccounts())
            || parseBooleanFromString(response.getWorkplaceRetirement().getHasPlansEligibleForChangeContributions())
            || parseBooleanFromString(
                    response.getWorkplaceRetirement().getHasPlansEligibleForChangeContributions());
    if (!b) {
```

or if you perfer more java 8 syntax

```
    Stream<Boolean> bools = Stream.of(parseBooleanFromString(response.getBuy().getHasEligibleAccounts()),
            parseBooleanFromString(response.getSell().getHasEligibleAccounts()),
            parseBooleanFromString(response.getExchange().getHasEligibleAccounts()),
            parseBooleanFromString(response.getWorkplaceRetirement().getHasPlansEligibleForChangeContributions()),
            parseBooleanFromString(response.getWorkplaceRetirement().getHasPlansEligibleForChangeContributions()));

    boolean c = ! bools.anyMatch(e -> e);

    if (!c) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
private boolean checkEligibility(LaunchPoints response) {
    final String trueStr = "true";
    if (trueStr.equals(response.getBuy().getHasEligibleAccounts()))  return true;
    if (trueStr.equals(response.getSell().getHasEligibleAccounts())) return true;

    [...]

    return false;         
}
```

The idea is, skip the parsing boolean, just check for "true" and make your conditions more readable.

Comment: this is not what I meant. There is no need for parsing.